# Print all the unique elements of an array

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to print all the unique elements of a given array using a binary search tree.

What I am doing:

1. Input all the numbers in an array.
2. Search for each element of the array one by one in the bst,

   - if (an element is not found in the bst)

     - put it there and print it
   - else

     - go to the next element

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct node
{   
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} *root = NULL;

void insert(struct node *n, int value)
{
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->data = value;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
        printf("%d ", value);
        return;
    }

    if ((n->data) == value)
        return;
    if ((n->data) > value)
        insert(n->left, value);
    else
        insert(n->right, value);
}   

int main()
{
    int a[100], i, n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("After removal of duplicates, the new list is : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(root, a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a few bugs, your function insert, should return a struct node*, otherwise you will not build a binary search tree.
In your initial code, when you call insert, you are always calling with a empty node.

this is what you should do, with minimal changes.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{   
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} *root = NULL;

struct node* insert(struct node *n, int value)
{
    if (n == NULL){
        n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->data = value;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
        printf("inserted %d\n", value);
        return n;
    }else{
        if( value == n->data){
            printf("Duplicated Value %d\n", value);
            return n;
        }
        if ( (n->data) > value ){
            n->left = insert(n->left, value);
        }else{
            n->right = insert(n->right, value);
        }
        return n;
    }
}   

int main()
{
    int a[100], i, n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("After removal of duplicates, the new list is : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        root = insert(root, a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html) should be helpfull and this is a testing [example](http://ideone.com/AUMkjt). ;)

You should create the array AFTER, you know the size, otherwise you may be allocating too much memory. And of course, you should give the user the possibility to create a binary tree with more than 100 elements

```
int i, n;
printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

First :
Do not return in void .. but if you like to you need to return the address of the tree because its change every time you call the function!!
 In your past code you have send a different tree every time the node is not connected with his left and right ..

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{   
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} *root = NULL;

struct node* insert(struct node *n, int value)
{

    if (n == NULL){
        n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->data = value;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
        printf("%d ", value);
        return n;
    }

    else if( value == n->data)
              return n;

    else  if ((n->data) > value)
               n->left = insert(n->left, value);

        else
            insert(n->right, value);

        return n;
    }


int main()
{
    int a[100], i, n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("After removal of duplicates, the new list is : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        root = insert(root, a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Ps : the guy  there tell you :

```
int i, n;
printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

you cant do that in c !! 
you must know the size of the table you cannot make a table with length is a variable !
(for allocate a size that you just need in c use a linked-list )

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    struct node
{   
  int data;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
} *root = NULL;

struct node* insert(struct node *n, int value)
{

  if (n == NULL){
    n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->data = value;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    printf("%d ", value);
    return n;
}

else if( value == n->data)
          return n;

else  if ((n->data) > value)
           n->left = insert(n->left, value);

    else
        insert(n->right, value);

    return n;
}


int main()
{
  int a[100], i, n;
  printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  printf("After removal of duplicates, the new list is : \n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    root = insert(root, a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

You can modify the code for dynamic allocation.

```
int *a,n;
scanf("%d",n);
a = (int)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```